# Dynamic factor analysis: MLE vs. PCA

Tags: pca, maximum-likelihood, factor-analysis

Consider the following dynamic factor model:

\begin{align}
X_{t}=\Lambda F_{t}+e_{t}    
\end{align}

where $F_t$ is a $k \times 1$ vector of latent factors, $\Lambda$ is an $N \times k$ matrix of coefficients, and $e_{t}$ is an $N \times 1$ vector of idiosyncratic disturbances. In classical factor analysis, $F_t$ and $e_t$ are mutually uncorrelated i.i.d. sequences of random variables, and $e_t$ has a diagonal covariance matrix $\Sigma_{ee}$. With $N$ fixed:

1. The *maximum likelihood* estimates of $\lambda$ for arbitrary $\widetilde{\Sigma}_{ee}$ are the eigenvectors of $\widetilde{\Sigma}^{-\frac{1}{2}}_{ee}\widehat{\Sigma}_{XX}\widetilde{\Sigma}^{-\frac{1}{2}}_{ee}$.
2. The *principal components* estimates, on the other hand, are the eigenvectors of $\widehat{\Sigma}_{XX}$ ; which evidently correspond to the maximum likelihood estimates only when ${\Sigma}_{ee}$ is a scalar matrix.

In this context, Boivin & Ng (2005, p. 174) state that: "Accordingly, for a given N, the principal components estimator can be expected to be less precise the further are the errors from being homoskedastic and mutually uncorrelated." Could someone clarify why this statement is true?

(Statement taken from: Boivin, J., & Ng, S. (2006). Are more data always better for factor analysis? Journal of Econometrics, 132(1), 169-194.)

Comment: The quoted expression merely is a way of saying, in words, that $\widetilde\Sigma_{ee}$ is far from the identity matrix.  It doesn't add anything to what's already stated in (1).